# Filter a DataGridView by multiple keys or words

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering

I am trying to filter my Datagridview by using DefaultView.RowFilter and currently can sort a list by a single word easily. My question is how do I Filter it by multiple words. Here is an example

My datagridview would consist of:

1 Topeka

2 Manhattan

3 Dallas

4 Dallas

5 Topeka

6 Wichita

I would then type "Wichita,Dallas,Manhattan" or "Wichita, Dallas, Manhattan" in a text box and it would then filter my DataGrid to only show

2 Manhattan

3 Dallas

4 Dallas

6 Wichita

Here is my Code. It does not like having an array value where the '%{s}%' is But works for a single filter such as '%{FilterTextBox.Text}%' with FilterTextBox.Text being "Dallas"  or even "Dall" for example.

```
private void FilterTxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uxFilterTxtbox.Text != "Type Here...") //IGNORE... This is for my watermark capibility
    {
        string[] s = uxFilterTxtbox.Text.Split(',');

        (uxWiuInfoGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
                    $"WiuAddressCol + SubDivLongNameCol + StationNameCol + LineSegCol + MilepostCol + MilepostSuffixCol LIKE '%{s}%'";
    }
}
```

Comment: The row filter uses SQL-like syntax. You would have to OR each condition together.

Comment: Thank you I posted a quick solution below. If there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the best way, but this does exactly what is needed. It will do as many filters as you want long as you separate them by a ',' . There can be spaces between words and you can even put spaces before or after the comma due to me using Trim() on each split.

```
private void FilterTxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string allColumns = "WiuAddressCol + SubDivLongNameCol + StationNameCol + LineSegCol + MilepostCol + MilepostSuffixCol";

    if (uxFilterTxtbox.Text != "Type Here...")
    {
        string[] split = uxFilterTxtbox.Text.Split(',');

        var mainSearchString = allColumns + " LIKE '%"+ split[0]?.Trim( )+ "%'";

        if (split.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
            {
                mainSearchString += " OR "+ allColumns + " LIKE '%" + split[i]?.Trim() + "%'";
            }
            (uxWiuInfoGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = mainSearchString;
        }
        else
        {
            (uxWiuInfoGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = mainSearchString;
        }

    }
}
```